# Exclude Submenu in Typoscript without hiding its parent

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to exlude a submenu without hiding its parent menu

That is my idea, but it doesn't work:

```
MENU = HMENU
MENU {

  special = directory
  special.value = 2

  1 = TMENU

  1.expAll = 1




  1.expAll.if {
    value = 97
    equals.field = pid
    negate = 1
  }
  ...
```

Thank you for help

Comment: What if you try to set **if** property not on `MENU.1.expAll`, but on `MENU.2.stdWrap`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set "Hide in Menu" option, so that in future anyone can do it.